# Nodejs - load module once and use in many different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My project directory looks something like this:

```
MyProject
    -app.js
    -routes
        -routeone
        -routetwo
```

Inside of my app.js file it looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var myModule= require('myModule');
app.use(myModule());

var routeone = require('./routes/routeone');
var routetwo = require('./routes/routetwo');

app.use('/routeone', routeone);
app.use('/routetwo', routetwo);
.
.
.
```

Each route file looks something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
    //Need to call myModule's createUser function. How do I call it here?
});
module.exports = router;
```

As you can see I have a dependency on the myModule module. I need to call a function in this module in every route.I may have many more routes in the future. I would like to avoid specifying this (calling require) in every single route file because in the future if I have hundreds of route and say the module now accepts options I would need to to every single file and since this manually. Is there a way to require it once (e.g in the app.js file) and then be able to use it everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your route modules as such that during the time of creation(`require call`) they get their dependencies injected. I have added a sample below

route.js

```
module.exports = function(myModule, router, dep1, dep2){
router.post()
//use my module, dep1 and dep2

}
```

app.js

```
var mymodule = require('./myModule')
var dep1 = require('./dep1');
var dep2 = require('./dep2');
var router = express.Router();
var route = require('route')(mymodule, router, dep1, dep2);
```

### Update - For returning router instance from route.js

route.js

```
module.exports = function(myModule, dep1, dep2){
router.post()
//other router invocations
return router
}
```

In app.js

```
var customRouter = require('route')(mymodule, router, dep1, dep2);
```

the customRouter will be an router instance since thats what is being returned by te invoked function in route.js

Comment: I have tried the following: App.js:  var routeone = require('./routes/routeone')(myModule,router);app.use('/routeone', routeone); . My route.js looks like this: module.exports = function(myModule,router){router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {});}. When I run the app I get the following error: TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think it requires a router to be exported, but with your example a function is being exported in route.js?

Comment: you can just return router from your function, check the update please !

Comment: With this code though, wont a router.post() handler be called every single time? This is not right.

Comment: what are you referring to when you say every single time ?